# How do I print this array after calling a function upon it?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

The following code block is only part of a larger one. In the program, I want to find the definite integral of a polynomial that needs to be inputted by the user.

I'm new to C and so I'm having a hard time trying to learn the syntax with regards to pointers. I find them very confusing.
So if you'll look at the code block below, I want to print the elements contained in the array `coefficients` just so I can see if the elements inputted are being stored in the array but to no avail. The program just terminates after the `inputCoeffs()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void inputDegree(int *deg) {
    printf("Enter the degree of the polynomial: \n");
    scanf("%d", *&deg);
}

void inputCoeffs(int deg, double *coeffs) {
    printf("Enter the coefficients of the polynomial (A, B, C,...): \n");
    for(int  i = 0; i <= deg; i++) {
        scanf("%lf", &coeffs[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int degree;
    double lowerLimit;
    double upperLimit;
    double integral;
    double *coefficients = NULL;
    double *integralCoefficients = NULL;

    inputDegree(&degree);

    coefficients = (double*)malloc((degree + 1) * sizeof(double));
    integralCoefficients = (double*)malloc((degree + 1) * sizeof(double));

    inputCoeffs(degree, &coefficients);

    for(i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {
        printf("\t%lf\n", coefficients[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inputCoeffs(degree, &coefficients);` should be `inputCoeffs(degree, coefficients);`. I think the compiler should have had a warning on that line as the passed in type for the second arg is different to the type defined by the function. If not, turn up your compiler warnings. Always heed and fix all compiler warnings.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, it worked! Could you explain a little bit regarding that? Because the way I see it is that when I called the `inputDegree` function in `main`, it had a `&` in its argument, considering that the function needs a pointer to be passed to it. So I thought maybe that's how it works for `inputCoeffs` too?

Comment: The difference is that `degree` is not a pointer whereas `coefficients` is already a pointer.

Comment: @kaylum my compiler gives a warning `a.c:30:25: warning: passing argument 2 of 'inputCoeffs' from incompatible pointer type
     inputCoeffs(degree, &coefficients);`

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
scanf("%d", *&deg);
```

it is enough to write

```
scanf("%d", deg);
```

It is unclear why you are allocating memory one element greater than the value of degree.

```
coefficients = (double*)malloc((degree + 1) * sizeof(double));
```

In this case the allocated array has `degree + 1` elements.

The type of the second argument in this call

```
inputCoeffs(degree, &coefficients);
```

is invalid. There shall be

```
inputCoeffs(degree, coefficients);
```

Comment: Regarding the line `coefficients = (double*)malloc((degree + 1) * sizeof(double));`, I just tried removing the `+ 1` and my intended program still works. Why is that so? My reasoning for putting that `+ 1` is that for instance, the inputted `degree` is 2, the polynomial needs degree + 1 = 3 (A B C, as in Ax^2 + Bx + C) allocated memory.

Comment: @PauloVictorio If you allocated less memory than required then the program has undefined behavior. It can work because malloc usually allocates memory of chunks  multiplied by the paragraph size.

Answer (score 0):

The & operator is used to get a pointer to an existing variable, while * is used to dereference a pointer. Therefore

```
inputCoeffs(degree, &coefficients);
```

Makes no sense, because `coefficients` is already a pointer. inputCoeffs
accepts a pointer so you can just write

```
inputCoeffs(degree, coefficients);
```

Since the & and * operators basically do the opposite, this line

```
scanf("%d", *&deg);
```

is not an error, but could also just be written as

```
scanf("%d", deg);
```

Also, you should call free when ever you use malloc, so add to the end of the code:

```
free(coefficients);
free(integralCoefficients);
```